# temporizar animação com css

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

boa tarde, preciso fazer uma animação parecida com a que esta no video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKo0RMtZ7g4&feature=youtu.be.

mais nao estou conseguindo ajustar o tempo.

```css
 .container {
height: 600px;
width: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
  }

  .centro {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .parallax {
height: 600px;
width: 160px;
background-image: url('img/intel_hybrid_160_bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center;
background-attachment: scroll;

  }

  .logo {
position: absolute;
top: 95%;
left: 70%;
transform: translate(-95%, -100%);
  }

  .titulo1 {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: -100%;
list-style: none;
animation: teste 0.3s ease-out both;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes teste {
0% {
  top: 40%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

100% {
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
  }



  .titulo2 {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: -100%;
list-style: none;
animation-name: teste2;
animation-duration: 0.3s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-out both;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes teste2 {
0% {
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

100% {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
  }


  .titulo3 {
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: -100%;
list-style: none;
animation-name: teste3;
animation-duration: 0.3s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: ease-out both;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes teste3 {
0% {
  top: 60%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

100% {
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
  }



  .kenburns-top {
-webkit-animation: kenburns-top 5s ease-out both;
animation: kenburns-top 5s ease-out both;
  }

  /* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2019-2-18 15:14:58
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

  /**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation kenburns-top
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
  @-webkit-keyframes kenburns-top {
0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 16%;
  transform-origin: 50% 16%;
}

100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25) translateY(-15px);
  transform: scale(1.25) translateY(-15px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
}
  }

  @keyframes kenburns-top {
0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 16%;
  transform-origin: 50% 16%;
}

100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25) translateY(-15px);
  transform: scale(1.25) translateY(-15px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="container centro">

<div class="parallax kenburns-top"></div>

<div class="logo">
  <img src="img/intel_hybrid_160_logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
</div>

<ul class="">
  <li><img src="img/intel_hybrid_160_copy1a.png" class="titulo1" id="titulo-1"></li>
  <li><img src="img/intel_hybrid_160_copy1b.png" class="titulo2" id="titulo-2"></li>
  <li><img src="img/intel_hybrid_160_copy1c.png" class="titulo3" id="titulo-3"></li>
</ul>



  </div>
```

Comment: Qual exatamente?

Comment: tenho 3 classes, titulo1, titulo2 e titulo3.
gostaria que assim que p titulo1 entrasse demorasse 1 segundo e entrasse o titulo2, 1 segundo o titulo3 e depois os 3 dessem opacity: 1;

deu para intender ?

Comment: você reparou que repete a titulo2, não?

Comment: sim, reparei ... mais fazendo isso no  titulo1, titulo2 para eu ter uma ideia. o resto fica facil ... pois tenho mais uns 10 titulos para fazer isso

Comment: Cara não entendi o efeito que vc comentou ai, vc quer que vá entrando 1 por 1 de 1 em 1 segundo, até os 3 estarem na tela, e depois disso o que vc quer fazer?

Comment: depois quero que suma da tela, axo que usaria o opacity.

Comment: editei a pergunta, creio que agora de para intender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Cara seu código estava meio confuso, então resolvi fazer um modelo do zero</sup>

**Fiz essa imagem sem** `overflow:hidden` no *container*, apenas para te ajudar a entender melhor! 
*Mais abaixo segue o código da versão final...*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha ideia foi fazer um *container* principal, nele coloquei um *pseudo elemento* `::after` e usei a propriedade `transform:scale` para mudar o tamanho do "fundo".

Dentro desse `container` eu coloquei duas `divs` com class `.box` e dentro dessa `div` `.box` eu coloquei os `itens`. Assim quando der o tempo da animação dos filhos entrando eu faço um `fadeOut` desse .box usando `opacity`, dessa forma ele some assim como os seus filhos.

Os itens estão alinhado com um `margin-left` negativo dentro do `.box`, e na animação eu coloco eles de volta dentro do `.box` com `margin-left:0;` no `item`.

Todas as animações eu fiz com `@keyframes`. Para selecionar cada .box eu usei `nth-child`, assim como usei tb `nth-child` para controlar cada um dos itens dentro do `.box`, dessa forma usando o valor de `delay` do `animation` eu consegui sincronizar tudo. Cada filho entra com um `delay` de `1 segundo`, dessa forma o primeiro `.box` tem `5 segundo` de animação, e o segundo `.box:nth-child(2)` começa com um `delay` de `5 segundo`

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    overflow: hidden;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: container-anima 10s linear forwards;
    transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes container-anima {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(2);
    }
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
    position: absolute;
    animation: box-anima 1s linear forwards 4s;
}
@keyframes box-anima {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -200%;
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 1s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 2s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 3s;
}
@keyframes item-anima {
    0% {
        margin-left: -200%;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
    animation: box-anima 1s linear forwards 9s;
}
.box:nth-child(2) .item {
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 6s;
}
.box:nth-child(2) .item:nth-child(2) {
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 7s;
}
.box:nth-child(2) .item:nth-child(3) {
    animation: item-anima 1s linear forwards 8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 2</div>
        <div class="item">item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="item">item 1 / 2</div>
        <div class="item">item 2 / 2</div>
        <div class="item">item 3 / 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cara era exatamente isso ... muito obrigado

Comment: @RoneyBerti legal que deu certo então. Repare sempre no valor do delay para ajustar as coisas caso precise. []´s